# How to get Localization Locale Property LocaleName string in Localiztion Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

Custom Property Drawer

I want to get name for locale in Unity Localization
but the code below errors null property.
how to get name of locale in property drawer?

```
    SerializedProperty locale = property.FindPropertyRelative("locale");
    SerializedProperty localeName = locale.serializedObject.FindProperty("LocaleName");
    Debug.Log(localeName.stringValue);
```

Actuial Code

```
    [System.Serializable]
    public class LocalizationButtonData
    {
        public Locale locale;
        public Button.Transition buttonTransition;
        public Sprite normalSprite;
        public SpriteState spriteState;
        public ColorBlock colors;
        public RuntimeAnimatorController controller;
    }
    
    public class LocalizationButton : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Image ImageComponent;
        private Button buttonComponent;
        public LocalizationButtonData[] localizationTextFontData;
    }
```

Locale Class:

```
namespace UnityEngine.Localization
{
    public class Locale : ScriptableObject, IEquatable<Locale>, IComparable<Locale>, ISerializationCallbackReceiver
    {
        public Locale();

        public virtual IFormatProvider Formatter { get; set; }
        public bool UseCustomFormatter { get; set; }
        public string LocaleName { get; set; }
        public string CustomFormatterCode { get; set; }
        public LocaleIdentifier Identifier { get; set; }
        public MetadataCollection Metadata { get; set; }
        public ushort SortOrder { get; set; }

        public static Locale CreateLocale(string code);
        public static Locale CreateLocale(LocaleIdentifier identifier);
        public static Locale CreateLocale(SystemLanguage language);
        public static Locale CreateLocale(CultureInfo cultureInfo);
        public int CompareTo(Locale other);
        public bool Equals(Locale other);
        public virtual Locale GetFallback();
        public void OnAfterDeserialize();
        public void OnBeforeSerialize();
        public override string ToString();
    }
}
```

Locale Class is metadata

Sorry For Insufficient explanation.

Comment: Could you show us the actual class this is supposed to access ... we have no clue what `locale` and `LocaleName` points to

Comment: Sorry For Insufficient explanation. I Updated it

Answer (score 1):

The `LocaleName` is a **property** and the Unity serializer doesn't serialize those, only **fields**.

You will need to know the according serialized field name - which is `m_LocaleName`.

---

Also

```
locale.serializedObject
```

again refers to **your** parent class object your main target property belongs to since this `locale` field still is a part of it. This is **not** the `SeriaizedObject` of the according **assigned** `Locale` object.

What you need to do is get access to the object reference and go through a new `SeriailizedObject` like e.g.

```
var locale = property.FindPropertyRelative("locale");

if(locale.objectReferenceValue)
{
    var localeSerializedObject = new SerializedObject(locale.objectReferenceValue);

    localeSerializedObject.Update();

    var localeName = localeSerializedObject.FindProperty("m_LocaleName");
    Debug.Log(localeName.stringValue);


    ...

    // if you are going to modify anything 
    localeSerializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
```